# sort multiple atributes into one in sql php

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I want to know how will be the sql query to obtain a select depending on table atribute NumberRecords but there are many rows with the same number like 1,2 so i will just like to to know which are 1 and 2.

and this is my code and a lot of them come out

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customer_service_experts');
                  if (!$con) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                  }

                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee_product` where NumberRecords =2";

                  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                          $NumberRecords = $row["NumberRecords "];


                          echo "<option  value='".$NumberRecords ."'>".$NumberRecords ."</option> ";
                      }
```

This is the select i want from this table

```html
<form>
<select>
  <option value="1">Number record 1</option>
  <option value="2">Number record 2</option>
  </select>
  </form>
```

[This image is my table epmloyee_products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcDDh.png)

Comment: can you clarify? Im confused on what you need.

Comment: i just updated the table or the pic

Comment: ok and what SQL query have you already tried?

Comment: Also, is this `select` inside a `form`? you need to show the entire form.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `employee_product` where NumberRecords =2                             and i have tried SELECT * FROM `employee_product` where NumberRecords =1 but i dont get 1 or 2

Comment: yeah it is inside a form

Comment: ok, edit your original question and add your `form` , PHP and SQL

Comment: its obviously not everything. Where are your form attributes and your PHP that handles the requests? is it POST/GET? please show all that you have tried.

Comment: ok my php code what i tried is there

Comment: ok, its looking a bit better. Can you tell me how your datatypes are set in your database for `NumberRecords`? is it `INT`, `VARCHAR`... ?

Comment: NumberRecords is  int

Comment: i hope u understand instead of geting 2,2,2,2 on my select i just want to get one 2 only

Comment: oh. I see what you mean. yo need to group them.

Comment: how ? i just want to get a single number for 1 and 2 onmy table

Comment: look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres an extra space on this line:

```
 $NumberRecords = $row["NumberRecords "];
```

change it to this:

```
 $NumberRecords = $row["NumberRecords"];
```

However, if you are looking to get only one row as a result, then you need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee_product` WHERE NumberRecords =2 GROUP BY NumberRecords
```

Comment: so this will get me the number by it self?

Comment: you need to try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: yes it perfectly does thanks so much and for taking the time to help me out

Comment: no problem. im glad you tried it.